# WAR module can't connect EJB module inside Wicket class

Tags: java, maven, ejb, wicket

Last time I try learn Maven Enterprice Aplication with Wicket but I can’t start.

I use:
Netbeans 8.2,
Wicket 7,
EJB3,
wildfly 10

Project structure:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>SampleWicketProject</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>SampleWicketProject</name>
  <modules>
    <module>SampleWicketProject-ear</module>
    <module>SampleWicketProject-web</module>
    <module>SampleWicketProject-ejb</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

SampleWicketProject-ear pom:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

        <parent>
        <artifactId>SampleWicketProject</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
      </parent>

        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>SampleWicketProject-ear</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>ear</packaging>

        <name>SampleWicketProject-ear</name>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        </properties>

        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <version>6</version>
                        <defaultLibBundleDir>lib</defaultLibBundleDir>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>SampleWicketProject-ejb</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>ejb</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.example</groupId>
                <artifactId>SampleWicketProject-web</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
                <type>war</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

SampleWicketProject-ejb pom:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>SampleWicketProject</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleWicketProject-ejb</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>ejb</packaging>

    <name>SampleWicketProject-ejb</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>unknown.binary</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen-4.3.1.Final</artifactId>
            <version>SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

SampleWicketProject-ejb persistance.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="myPersistance" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>java:/jboss/datasources/PostgreDataSource</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <class>com.example.entities.Person</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
       <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

SampleWicketProject-ejb interface:

```
package com.example.Repository;

import com.example.entities.Person;
import javax.ejb.Local;

//@Local
public interface NewSessionBeanLocal {

    public void addPerson(Person person);
}
```

SampleWicketProject-ejb class:

```
package com.example.Repository;

import com.example.entities.Person;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.ejb.LocalBean;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
//@LocalBean
public class NewSessionBean  implements NewSessionBeanLocal{

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "myPersistance")
    EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public void addPerson(Person person) {
        em.persist(person);
    }
}
```

SampleWicketProject-web pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
    <artifactId>SampleWicketProject</artifactId>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleWicketProject-web</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>SampleWicketProject-web</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <wicket.version>7.6.0</wicket.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>SampleWicketProject-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-core</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>          
        <dependency>  
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>  
            <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>  
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>  
        </dependency>        
        <dependency>  
           <groupId>org.wicketstuff</groupId>  
           <artifactId>wicketstuff-javaee-inject</artifactId>  
           <version>${wicket.version}</version>  
       </dependency>          
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>**</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>            
    </build>

</project>
```

SampleWicketProject-web web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
     version="3.1">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>SampleWicketProject-web</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
            <param-value>com.example.WicketApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SampleWicketProject-web</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>        
</web-app>
```

SampleWicketProject-web classes:

WicketApplication.class

```
package com.example;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
ipackage com.example;

import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;
import org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEComponentInjector;

public class WicketApplication extends WebApplication{

    @Override
    public Class<? extends WebPage> getHomePage() 
    {
        return StartPage.class;
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(){
        super.init();
        getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(new JavaEEComponentInjector(this));
    }
}
```

StartPage.class

```
package com.example;

import com.example.Repository.NewSessionBeanLocal;
import com.example.entities.Person;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class StartPage extends WebPage {

    @EJB
    NewSessionBeanLocal beanLocal;

    public StartPage() {
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setSurname("ABC");
        person.setUsername("DEF");

        beanLocal.addPerson(person);
    }    
}
```

StartPage.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>Hello World : Project Wicket + EJB</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I added EJB dependency to WAR module but all the time i have this error:

```
    16:28:45,104 ERROR [org.apache.wicket.DefaultExceptionMapper] (default task-2) Unexpected error occurred: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public com.example.StartPage()'. An exception has been thrown during construction!
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:194)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:67)
    at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:102)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:271)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:169)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.isPageStateless(WebPageRenderer.java:287)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.shouldRenderPageAndWriteResponse(WebPageRenderer.java:329)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:193)
    at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
    at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
    at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:175)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/example/Repository/NewSessionBeanLocal;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.findFields(Injector.java:145)
    at org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.inject(Injector.java:93)
    at org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEComponentInjector.inject(JavaEEComponentInjector.java:68)
    at org.wicketstuff.javaee.injection.JavaEEComponentInjector.onInstantiation(JavaEEComponentInjector.java:74)
    at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:38)
    at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:34)
    at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.notify(ListenerCollection.java:80)
    at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.onInstantiation(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:33)
    at org.apache.wicket.Component.<init>(Component.java:688)
    at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.<init>(MarkupContainer.java:180)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.<init>(Page.java:170)
    at org.apache.wicket.Page.<init>(Page.java:134)
    at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.<init>(WebPage.java:75)
    at com.example.StartPage.<init>(StartPage.java:17)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.Repository.NewSessionBeanLocal from [Module "deployment.SampleWicketProject-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
    ... 68 more
```

I don’t understand what is wrong. It doesn't matter if I add another dependences like hibernate, jpa … or no. I correctly set up the database on Wildfly local server. I think it's looks like WAR have some problem with EJB module inside wicket class...? Does anybody have a clue what might be the problem? Thank you for any advice

Comment: You have `<artifactId>SampleWicketProject-ejb</artifactId>` in scope `provided`, but it seems your configuration cannot access this jar? Thus you get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`

Comment: Thank You for answer. Yes, You have right my configuration cannot access this (EJB) jar even i add <type>jar</type> for to dependency inside WAR like this:        
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>SampleWicketProject-ejb</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Comment: scope `provided` means that the war will not contain the dependency. So you have to make sure you add the dependency on runtime. Or remove the `scope` all together to include it in the `WAR`

Comment: If I remove EJB scope: <scope>provided</scope> inside WAR I have this same error, nothing change. When I try ‘Clean and Build’ in Netbeans for  all modules everything is ok. It looks like WAR see EJB module when I write code but dont see after compilation.

Comment: If you add `<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>` to the `maven-war-plugin` `<configuration>` section, it should add all the classes.

Comment: Even I add „<attachClasses>true</attachClasses>” inside WAR pom it doesn't help. Still I have this same errors, anyway thank You for help!

Comment: I am sorry I did not notice.. I have error like before:
Unexpected error occurred: org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public com.example.StartPage()'. An exception has been thrown during construction!

But another causeds:

Comment: -java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

-java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not locate ejb of class [[interface com.example.Repository.NewSessionBeanLocal]] 

-javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: env/com.example.Repository.NewSessionBeanLocal -- service jboss.naming.context.java.module."SampleWicketProject-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT"."SampleWicketProject-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT".env."com.example.Repository.NewSessionBeanLocal"